# Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'm able to run a script on linux but on that same machine, if apache runs the script, I get `TimeoutException. Message: connection refused`

Looking into geckodriver.log, it says:

```
1604976847149   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilehZbDYR" 

Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11

Running without a11y support!

*** You are running in headless mode.
```

I think this part is just a warning - not an error? I'm not sure.

To start Firefox, I'm basically doing this: https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/blob/master/instapy/browser.py

Which doesn't use XVFB or any virtual display, just "-headless" and the Firefox extension.

Any idea why this code would run flawless on command line but not if it's called from apache?

Here's the full trace:

```
TimeoutException: Message: connection refused

  File "django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "mainapp/views.py", line 277, in api
    send_message(message, recipient_username)
  File "scripts/browser_login.py", line 434, in send_message
    driver = browser_login(username, password)
  File "scripts/browser_login.py", line 123, in browser_login
    options=firefox_options,
  File "selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 162, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

This happens exactly 60 seconds after starting the script. It sits on the webdriver initialization.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why this code would run flawless on command line but not if it's called from apache?
> This happens exactly 60 seconds after starting the script. It sits on the webdriver initialization.

It may happen due to `geckodriver` installation failure or version incompatibility between `geckodriver` and Firefox, to prevent this use [`geckodriver-autoinstaller`](https://pypi.org/project/geckodriver-autoinstaller/) to automatically download and install `geckodriver` that supports the currently installed version of Firefox.

1. Add the following module to `requirements.txt` and install it.

```py
geckodriver-autoinstaller==0.1.0
```

2. Remove your previous `geckodriver` installation code from `browser.py` and add the following lines at the beginning.

```py
import geckodriver_autoinstaller  
geckodriver_autoinstaller.install()
```

3. If you're doing remote execution then do the necessary settings to run command `pip install -r requirements.txt` everytime before executing any python file.
4. Finally run the script `browser.py`.

Comment: Firefox is 68.12.0esr and geckodriver is 0.26.0 in my test environment.

Comment: As per [Mozilla geckodriver supported platforms](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html) for Firefox version >= 60, geckodriver version should be >= 0.26.0 and Selenium version >= 3.11 with Python 3.14. Check if all these are satisfied.

Comment: Selenium is 3.11 but Python is 2.7

Comment: You can either upgrade to Python 3 OR at [line 38](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/blob/master/instapy/browser.py) specify the version of `geckodriver`, otherwise it will fetch the latest version which doesn't support Python 2.7. Specify version as `gdd.download_and_install("v0.20.1")`, also use Selenium 3.5 and Firefox versions between 55 and 62.